# panelGroup rendered tag not working

Tags: jsf, rendered-attribute

I have a `<h:panelGroup>` tag with a `rendered` attribute. The function it calls to determine whether it renders or not returns true, I have logged and printed this to make sure.

The structure looks as follows:

```
<h:form>
    <div><!-- content --></div>
    <h:panelGroup>
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean.function(parameter)} == true">
            <!-- content -->
        </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

The panelGroup with the rendered tag is never displayed, even though the function returns true. Any idea why this isn't working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem, that I have found(silly me) is that the rendered tag should be `rendered="#{bean.function(parameter) == true}"` as opposed to `rendered="#{bean.function(parameter)} == true"`

Comment: You can even omit the `== true` part altogether as the `function()` apparently returns a boolean already.